# get rid of PodSecurity warnings

Tags: kubernetes

I often use curl image to test out connectivity inside clusters:

`kubectl --kubeconfig ./kubeconfig run curly --image=curlimages/curl --rm -it --restart=Never -- /bin/sh`

However, with k8s v1.27+ a warning is emitted:

```
Warning: would violate PodSecurity "restricted:latest": allowPrivilegeEscalation != false 
(container "curly" must set securityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation=false), unrestricted capabilities (container "curly" must set securityContext.capabilities.drop=["ALL"]), 
runAsNonRoot != true (pod or container "curly" must set securityContext.runAsNonRoot=true), seccompProfile (pod or container "curly" must set securityContext.seccompProfile.type to "RuntimeDefault" or "Localhost")
```

I cant create a pod.yaml to set all these values as the pod needs to be interactive so how can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1):

maybe overrides can be helpful here

```
kubectl --kubeconfig ./kubeconfig run curly --image=curlimages/curl --rm -it --restart=Never --overrides='
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "spec": {
    "securityContext": {
      "allowPrivilegeEscalation": false,
      "runAsNonRoot": true
    }
  }
}' -- /bin/sh
```

Comment: That gave a CreateContainerConfigError  container has runAsNonRoot and image has non-numeric user. but yeah I did not know you could override the run command